# Where to Find a Control Template that Modifies the Suite Bar?

Tags: 2013

I'm working on a Sharepoint 2013 portal on which some changes were made to the suite bar.  I don't possess the Visual Studio solution that was used for these changes and cannot locae it.

Is it possible to search the server for the deployed control template and then reverse engineer it back to a solution file?  Or, is there a better approach to locating and modifying further the solution that controls the suite bar navigation?

Thanks for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find the name of the solution file you can download it from the server using powershell:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item("solutionfile.wsp").SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs("c:\temp\solutionfile.wsp")
```

You can rename the .wsp file to .cab which will let you open it and view the contents. Going through those file may help you re-create the solution in visual studio.

**To see all solutions:**
use either

```
Get-SPSolution
```

or

```
 $farm = Get-SPFarm
 $farm.Solutions | Format-Table
```

Comment: I don't have the name of the solution file.  Is there a way I can pull up all wsp files for the farm?

Comment: @SidC See my edit above

Comment: When I run Get-SPSolution, I receive The term is not recognize as the name of a cmdlet , function, script file or operable program.  I ran this at the root of the hard drive in Powershell

Comment: Run it in "SharePoint 2013 Management Shell". That will load all the required libraries for you.